# Layout glitch with SurfaceView in Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, surfaceview

I have a subclassed surfaceview that i want to add as view to a custom dialog. Problem is, that the surfaceview and the dialog don't work well together:

1. The surfaceview draws beyond the dialog's bounds.
2. When i hit the back button, first the surfaceview disappears, leaving an ugly dialog frame and some overlay buttons visible briefly before the dialog disappears in it's animated style.

Is it possible that surfaceviews' layouting is incompatible to dialogs, or that the dialogs' layouting works differently from the way activities do? I can't get a grip on the real problem that here...